# Is there any post_load in pydantic?

Tags: python, pydantic

Previously I used the [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library with the Flask. Some time ago I have tried FastAPI with [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/). At first glance `pydantic` seems similar to `masrhmallow` but on closer inspection they differ. And for me the main difference between them is [post_load](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending.html#pre-processing-and-post-processing-methods) methods which are from `marshmallow`. I can't find any analogs for it in `pydantic`.

`post_load` is decorator for post-processing methods. Using it I can handle return object on my own, can do whatever I want:

```
class ProductSchema(Schema):
    alias = fields.Str()
    category = fields.Str()
    brand = fields.Str()

    @post_load
    def check_alias(self, params, **kwargs):
        """One of the fields must be filled"""
        if not any([params.get('alias'), params.get('category'), params.get('brand')]):
            raise ValidationError('No alias provided', field='alias')
        return params
```

Besides it used not only for validation. Code example is just for visual understanding, do not analyze it, I have just invented it.

So my question is:
is there any analog for `post_load` in `pydantic`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not obvious but `pydantic's` validator returns value of the field.

## Pydantic v1

There are two ways to handle `post_load` conversions: [`validator`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) and
[`root_validator`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators).

`validator` gets the field value as argument and returns its value.
`root_validator` is the same but manipulates with the whole object.

```
from pydantic import validator, root_validator


class PaymentStatusSchema(BaseModel):
    order_id: str = Param(..., title="Order id in the shop")
    order_number: str = Param(..., title="Order number in chronological order")
    status: int = Param(..., title="Payment status")

    @validator("status")
    def convert_status(cls, status):
        return "active" if status == 1 else "inactive"

    @root_validator
    def validate_order_id(cls, values):
        """Check order id"""
        if not values.get('orderNumber') and not values.get('mdOrder'):
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='No order data provided')
        return values
```

By default `pydantic` runs validators as post-processing methods. For pre-processing you should use validators with `pre` argument:

```
    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def validate_order_id(cls, values):
        """Check order id"""
        # some code here
        return values
```

## Pydantic v2

In Pydantic v2 validators migrated: `validator` to [`field_validator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/functional_validators/#pydantic.functional_validators.field_validator) and `root_validator` to [`model_validator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/functional_validators/#pydantic.functional_validators.model_validator).

```
@field_validator('status')
@classmethod
def convert_status(cls, status: int):
    return "active" if status == 1 else "inactive"

@model_validator(mode='after')
@classmethod
def validate_order_id(cls, values):
    """Check order id"""
    if not values.get('orderNumber') and not values.get('mdOrder'):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='No order data provided')
    return values
```

For post or pre-processing use `mode` parameter.

Comment: pre is the argument of decorator root_validator 
`@root_validator(pre=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Pydantic's `@validator` [decorator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) to do pre-load, post-load, model validating etc.

Here is a Post load example

```
from pydantic import validator

class Person(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    second_name: str

    @validator("first_name")
    def make_it_formal(cls, first_name):
        return f"Mr. {first_name.capitalize()}"



p = Person(first_name="egvo", second_name="Example")

p.first_name
Out: Mr. Egvo
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also override `__init__` and post-process the instance there:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ProductSchema(BaseModel):
    alias: str
    category: str
    brand: str

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Do Pydantic validation
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Do things after Pydantic validation
        if not any([self.alias, self.category, self.brand]):
            raise ValueError("No alias provided")
```

Though this happens outside of Pydantic's validation.